# Is Google App Engine a good choice for the following project with heavy processing requirements

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to start a new project in GAE. However, before I start learning GAE (it's new to me), can someone tell me whether GAE is suitable for the job? I would like to start developing a website in which:

- users can submit large pdf files (<50 MB).
- These pdf files need to be processed, which requires a lot of computing power, it is time intensive.
- The user does not need to stay online when this processing is being performed. He should be able to leave and find the results of the processing the next day or see the current status of the processing.
- For the processing I start from an existing java project that uses [Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) for OCR.

Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Engine has all the tools that you need for this project.

1. Start by splitting your project into two modules: one for your app and another one for PDF processing code. You can specify different scaling methods and instance types for each module. There are scaling options that do not set a limit on a time to process a request - you can use one of them for your PDF processing module.
2. App Engine supports tasks. When a user submits a PDF file, you add a new task to a task queue. You can set different parameters on your task queue, e.g. the desired rate of execution.
3. It is possible to mix App Engine instances with Compute Engine instances. Compute Engine instances are cheaper and have fewer limitations on the type of code they can run, but you have to do more work to manage them.

It looks like you cannot run Tesseact on App Engine, because it's a native code. You will need to use an online service for processing or run it yourself on a Compute Engine instance.